# Cursor occasionally lose data when open in run time

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g, cursor

This is my cursor with SELECT statement which always return right result. But when i use it in a procedure, it sometimes get wrong result (return only one row).

This problem appears with a large frequency (~5-10 times per 1000 procedure call). Maybe this is known issues with oracle 10gR2 or some disadvantages in my procedure.

I hope I can understand why this happening and get the better solutions because I get ~5000 procedure calls per day.

This is my cursor which declared in procedure:

```
CURSOR cur_result (var_num NUMBER)
    IS
        SELECT
            m_username,
            m_password
        FROM
            M_USERS
        WHERE
            m_status   = 1
        AND rownum    <= var_num;
```

This is my procedure body:

```
p_num:=5;

-- the IF statement for guarantee the SELECT statement always
-- get more rows than p_num

LOCK TABLE M_USERS IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
OPEN cur_result (p_num);
LOOP
    FETCH
            cur_result 
        INTO
            p_username,
            p_password;
    -- the problems here: only 1 row is queried
    --                    the LOOP will exit after second time fetch
    IF (cur_result%NOTFOUND AND (cur_result%ROWCOUNT < p_num) ) THEN
        iserror    := 1;
        EXIT;
    END IF;


    EXIT WHEN cur_result%NOTFOUND;

    UPDATE
            M_USERS
        SET
            m_status = 2
        WHERE
                m_username = p_username
            AND m_password = p_password;
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur_result;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you believe that the query should return more rows?  I suppose it is theoretically possible that you have encountered an Oracle bug that causes a trivial query to return incorrect results.  It seems vastly more likely, though, that at the moment you query the `M_USERS` table, there are fewer than `p_num` rows that have an `m_status` of 1.

Comment: I replaced the code block for checking this condition by a comment sentence to simple the proc. And I can easy detected this problem when I call procedure again and they give me the right result.

Comment: Is this a single user system?  Or are there more than one user?  The fact that a query returns 5 rows at this instant says nothing about what that same query would have returned a moment ago.

Comment: This is a single user system (but multi-sessions) and we have to passed the test on this system before running on the main system (multi-users). There are many sessions running on the same time (from db developers and web developers) in this system.